# How to mask URL rails

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, routes

I am new to Rails. here trying to replace a word in URL. My `routes.rb` is:

```
resources :senders, only: [:index, :update]
 get '/senders/:id', constraints: { :id => /[0-9]+/ }, to: 'senders#show'
 put '/senders/:id', constraints: { :id => /[0-9]+/ }, to: 'senders#update'
 get '/senders/:id/check_status/:ip_index', constraints: { :id => /[0-9]+/, :ip_index => /[0-3]/ }, to: 'senders#check_status'
```

It shows in the url link as

```
localhost:3000/senders
```

but I want it to show as

```
localhost:3000/receivers
```

What are the changes I have to make to show receivers/173?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing anything in your controller, you can do the following:

```
resources :receivers, only: [:index, :update], controller: 'senders'
 get '/receivers/:id', constraints: { :id => /[0-9]+/ }, to: 'senders#show'
 put '/receivers/:id', constraints: { :id => /[0-9]+/ }, to: 'senders#update'
 get '/receivers/:id/check_status/:ip_index', constraints: { :id => /[0-9]+/, :ip_index => /[0-3]/ }, to: 'senders#check_status'
```

But you should also change your controller name and do the following:

First change your controller name.
Rename `app/controllers/senders_controller.rb` to `app/controllers/receivers_controller.rb`

And change the first line in the controller:
`SendersController < ApplicationController` to `ReceiversController < ApplicationController`

Then finally, change your `config/routes.rb` as below:

```
resources :receivers, only: [:index, :update]
     get '/receivers/:id', constraints: { :id => /[0-9]+/ }, to: 'receivers#show'
     put '/receivers/:id', constraints: { :id => /[0-9]+/ }, to: 'receivers#update'
     get '/receivers/:id/check_status/:ip_index', constraints: { :id => /[0-9]+/, :ip_index => /[0-3]/ }, to: 'receivers#check_status'
```

You can know more about Rails routing from the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: This answer is close, but not _quite_ right. In the first part describing route changes without changing anything in the controller, changing to `resources :receivers...` would break the `index` action because that would be routed to `ReceiversController`.

Comment: Thanks, That was really helpful!